# Is it possible to make an android app that will not lost at factory reset

Tags: android

I want to make an android app, that is used for store secure data and it is password protected. I want to make it like a default app in android, means does not lost at factory reset. Help me please......

Comment: You should contact Google and the intented device manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible.

Unless you make custom ROM with that app, and then flash it to your phone!